# Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/web-vitals'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

I am getting this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/web-vitals'
```

I want to use **useReportWebVitals **from next/web-vitals.

Reference: [Optimizing: Analytics](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/analytics)

I am using **next: 12.0.8** & **react: 17.0.2**

Note: I am using pages router in Next App

I tried removing node_modules, package-lock, .next and re-installing it
I also tried clearing the cache.

What am I doing wrong?

Your response will be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `next/web-vitals` was introduced in next v13.3.0, and so you'll likely need to upgrade if you want to use that.

Here's the [release tag that shows it](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.3.0).